Firebase hostingへデプロイしたWebAssemblyで「Unexpected token '<' 」のエラーが出るようになりました。
Blazor WebAssemblyアプリをFirebase Hostingにデプロイしています。最後にデプロイしたのが４月でこれまで問題なくブラウザで表示されていましたが、昨日デプロイしたところ、正しく表示されずブラウザの開発者ツールで確認したところ「Unexpected token '<' 」のエラーがjsファイルに対して出ていました。そのjsファイルを表示しようとするとindex.htmlの内容が表示されます。edgeでもchromeでも同じです。ローカル環境で「firebase serve」を試した場合は正しく表示されています。
念のためVisualStudioでBlazor WebAssemblyアプリを新規作成してそのままの状態でデプロイしてみましたが同じエラーがでていました。
当該jsファイルが見つからない場合に上記のようなエラーになるということはわかったのですが、デプロイが成功しているのなぜ見つからないのか？（ローカル環境でjsファイルを消して試すと同じエラーが出ます）
何か解決の手掛かりになる情報などありますでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

Unexpected token '<' でググって調べてみるということはしましたか？

とりあえず blazor webassembly unexpected token '<' で検索して上位に来るこれらの記事が参考になるかも。あとこれら記事程度に具体的な情報を記載した方が助言・回答を得られ易いでしょう。Blazor - Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0, Getting error while loading blazor webassembly. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' #34037, Blazor Hosted WebApp - Error after publishing, Invalid or unexpected token in WebAssembly

似たような質問が出てきたようです。Firebase側の問題でしょうか？
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78672565/firebase-deploy-gives-black-page-with-error-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-tok , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78674277/firebase-hosting-leads-to-blank-screen

firebase-toolsのバージョンを13.11.4から13.12.0にアップしたところ上記のエラーは出なくなり解決しました。古いバージョンに戻すと解決するという情報もありましたが、最新版で修正されていました。
